# Create int array from txt file with multilines and spaces between numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, sudoku

I have a sudoku checker. I need to catch numbers of the sudoku.txt into an array of ints in C.

My sudoku.txt is multi lined and the numbers are separated by " " space.

```
6 2 4 5 3 9 1 8 7
5 1 9 7 2 8 6 3 4
8 3 7 6 1 4 2 9 5
1 4 3 8 6 5 7 2 9
9 5 8 2 4 7 3 6 1
7 6 2 3 9 1 4 5 8
3 7 1 9 5 6 8 4 2
4 9 6 1 8 2 5 7 3
2 8 5 4 7 3 9 1 6
```

I want to load all the numbers in array like this.

E.G.:

```
int array[]={6, 2, 4, 5, 3, 9, 1, 8, 7, 5, 1, 9, 7, 2, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 3, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 9, 5, 1, 4, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 2, 9, 9, 5, 8, 2, 4, 7, 3, 6, 1, 7, 6, 2, 3, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3, 7, 1, 9, 5, 6, 8, 4, 2, 4, 9, 6, 1, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4, 7, 3, 9, 1, 6};
```

I've seen a lot of posts of txt to array of ints like 12345678 or 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 one line.
But multi lined and separated by " " not yet.

Code:

```
//
//  main.c
//  sudoku
//
//  Created by Ramón Serrano López on 23/1/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Ramón Serrano López. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sudoku_checker(int N ,int a[]){
    int i,j;
    int count=0;

    /* This loop calculate the sum of each row */
    /* and check foreach if it equals to (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9) = 45 o not*/
    for (i = 0; i < N*N; i = i+9) {
        int sumRow = 0;
        for (j = i; j < i+9; j++) {
            sumRow = sumRow + a[j];
        }
        if (sumRow != 45) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    /* This loop calculate the sum of each col*/
    /* and check foreach if it equals to (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9) = 45 o not*/
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int sumCol = 0;
        for (j = i; j < N*N; j = j+9) {
            sumCol = sumCol + a[j];
        }
        if (sumCol != 45) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Fails: %d\n", count);
    if(count==0)
        printf("OK\n");
    else
        printf("Successes\n");
}

int main()
{
    //info.txt it's the sudoku file
    FILE *myFile = fopen("/Users/ramonserranolopez/Desktop/SO/sudoku/sudoku/info.txt","r");
    int i, j, k, arrayofNumbers[81];
    if (myFile == NULL) {
        printf("the file could not be opened for reading\n");
    } else {
        for (i=0; i<81; i++) {
            fscanf(myFile, "%1d", &arrayofNumbers[i]);
        }
    }

    //provisional array to check if the function sudoku_cheker works
    //int a[]={6, 2, 4, 5, 3, 9, 1, 8, 7, 5, 1, 9, 7, 2, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 3, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 9, 5, 1, 4, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 2, 9, 9, 5, 8, 2, 4, 7, 3, 6, 1, 7, 6, 2, 3, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3, 7, 1, 9, 5, 6, 8, 4, 2, 4, 9, 6, 1, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4, 7, 3, 9, 1, 6};

    //prints the array
    int N = 9;
    for (j = 0; j < N*N; j = j+4) {
        for (k = j; k < j+4; k++) {
            printf("  %1d  ", arrayofNumbers[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }

     sudoku_checker(N,arrayofNumbers);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Just a note, any specific reason you din't check for the success of `fopen()`?

Comment: Also, please elaborate `doesn't work`.

Comment: I've checked the fopen it works successfully

Comment: @RamónSerranoLópez Sourav means, `if (myFile == NULL) {printf("the file could not be opened for reading\n"); exit_or_return_here();}` you must check for that otherwise your program will do some very wierd things.

Comment: @iharob the check it's ok

Comment: Ok, so why doesn't it work? It looks ok to me, so in principle it has to be working.

Comment: @RamónSerranoLópez How are you printing it?

Comment: @RamónSerranoLópez the `printf()` line we mean.

Comment: Post a *whole program* that attempts to read the file and then print it. Why are you making it so difficult for people to help you?

Comment: Yes because I suspect your read the data in a funciton using an array and returned the local variable's address and then tried to print somewhere else, post the whole program please.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths  I am sorry for any inconvenience im a little noobie on stack overflow it's my first day on this platform

Comment: @iharob the whole program it's posted the reading and the printing

Comment: @RamónSerranoLópez are the parts in separate functions.

Comment: The whole program is *not* posted. Where is your `main()` function? Where are your `#include` directives? You need to post an entire compilable program, as short as possible to demonstrate the issue. Without this, you're wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @RamónSerranoLópez are you sure the file exists? from the beggining we told you to check for that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69677/discussion-on-question-by-ramon-serrano-lopez-create-int-array-from-txt-file-wit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you did check if the file was opened you still continue reading when it failed, that's wrong, this code will not fail that way, but I assume it will not work either because your file apparently doesn't exist

Also, in the printing loop you are trying to print more elements than there are in the array, I've also fixed that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sudoku_checker(int N ,int a[])
{
    int i,j;
    int count;

    /* This loop calculate the sum of each row */
    /* and check foreach if it equals to (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9) = 45 o not*/
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N * N ; i = i + 9) 
    {
        int sumRow = 0;
        for (j = i; j < i + 9; j++) 
            sumRow = sumRow + a[j];
        if (sumRow != 45)
            count++;
    }

    /* This loop calculate the sum of each col*/
    /* and check foreach if it equals to (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9) = 45 o not*/
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        int sumCol = 0;

        for (j = i ; j < N * N; j = j + 9) 
            sumCol = sumCol + a[j];

        if (sumCol != 45)
            count++;
    }
    printf("Fails: %d\n", count);

    if (count == 0)
        printf("OK\n");
    else
        printf("Successes\n");
}

int main()
{
    //info.txt it's the sudoku file
    int i, j, k, arrayofNumbers[81];
    FILE *myFile;
    int N = 9;
    int readCount = 0;

    myFile = fopen("file.dat", "r");
    if (myFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("the file could not be opened for reading\n");
        /* you should abort the program, if the file was not found */
        return -1; 
    }

    while (fscanf(myFile, "%1d", &arrayofNumbers[i]) == 1)
        readCount++;

    for (j = 0 ; j < readCount ; ++j) 
    {
        printf("  %1d  ", arrayofNumbers[j]);
        if ((1 + j) % 4 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    sudoku_checker(N,arrayofNumbers);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I use your code it says that my file exists and print the array like this:  0    0    0    0  
  0    0    0    0  
  0    0    0    0  
  0    0    0    0  
  0    0    0    0  
  0    0    0    0  
  0    0    0    0  
  0    0    0    0  
  0    0    1606418432    32767  
  -2102815162    -332136427    -148998249    1495678624  
  -1188721324    167778272    1606416480    32767  
  16    0    1    0  
  104    1    1606578576    32767  
  1606416240    32767    1606423158    32767  
  1606416264    32767    1606416264    32767  
  1

Comment: Check your file content, try the updated code, I just noticed that you was not checking if the values were read from the file, en caso de no ser leidos, los valores del arreglo quedan sin inicializar y vas a obtener lo que llaman valores basura como los que tu programa está imprimiendo.

Comment: It's fixed and it's works. Gracias por la ayuda @iharob